# Use jq to append array contents from multiple files into one master array

Tags: json, jq

I'm attempting to use [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) to combine the data of many JSON files. However, most solutions I tried clobber the data and I end up losing most of it.

Each file looks something like this

```
{
  "Brand":"brand",
  "Fulfilled":5600,
  "Total":5626,
  "Data":[
    {
      "data":"data1"
    },
    {
      "data":"data2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to pull the contents from the main 'Data' array from each file and make it look something like this:

```
{
  "Everything":[
    {
      "data":"data1"
    },
    {
      "data":"data2"
    },
    {
      "data":"data3"
    },
    {
      "data":"data4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inputs` in combination with the `-n` flag to address all input documents:

```bash
jq -n '{Everything: [inputs.Data[]]}' *.json
```

```json
{
  "Everything": [
    {
      "data": "data1"
    },
    {
      "data": "data2"
    },
    {
      "data": "data3"
    },
    {
      "data": "data4"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6UvRKUcq_S1)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `-s` switch, there will be an implicit array wrapping around all objects emitted by the `*.json`, and so you can also do this without having to explicitly reference the `inputs` object:

```json
§ jq -s '{ Everything:[ .[].Data[] ] }' *.json
{
  "Everything": [
    {
      "data": "data1"
    },
    {
      "data": "data2"
    },
    {
      "data": "data1"
    },
    {
      "data": "data2"
    }
  ]
}
```